# fetch vs get() datastore pricing on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Which approach results in less Google App Engine data store hits:

1. a single dataobject.fetch(limit=10) OR
2. dataobject.get() repeated 10 times.

Comment: Do you mean, "query.fetch(10)" vs "db.get(key) x 10"?

Comment: No, I want to return the entire entity in both cases. And from the same link, it looks like get() costs less than fetch().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.get()` costs less than `query.fetch(limit)`.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs

Answer (score 2):

For (1): 1 x QUERY + 10 x GET (one per entry fetched) = 11 READ operations = 11 x 60 = 660 micropennies

For (2): 10 x GET  = 10 READ operations = 10 x 60 = 600 micropennis

Your cheapest best is to actually query and get only "keys" for the entries. This will work if you do not necessarily want to access data for each entry that you are fetching:

Cheapest: Query(keys_only=True): 1 x QUERY + 10 x SMALL_GET = 1 READ + 10 SMALL = 60 + 10*10 = 160 micropennies.

Note that the cheapest would be more expensive if you iterate over the keys you received and query each data again. The 10x10 = 100 micropennies would be the overhead in that case.